# C++ unable to link with library g++

Tags: c++

I can't figure how to properly link my libraries. I understand this question has been asked before and I've checked these links, but ld still cannot find my library.

I have a shared object file `libembed.so`, and a Cpp program `emb.cpp` in the same directory. I'm trying to run:

`g++ -llibembed emb.cpp`

This gives me

```
/usr/bin/ld.bdf.real: cannot find -llibembed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I try specifying the entire directory

`g++ -L /home/path/to/files/ -llibembed emb.cpp`

But I'm getting the exact same error. How do I properly link this library with my application?

Comment: you should write `g++ -lembed emb.cpp` without lib

Answer (score 1):

Try simply:

```
g++ -o my_app emb.cpp `pwd`/libembed.so
```

Or, assuming that `libembed.so` is always in the same directory as `my_app`

```
g++ -o my_app -L. -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN' emb.cpp -lembed
```

Basically, you need to specify two paths: one for `ld` linker to find the library when you link it using `-l` and another path that `ld.so` uses to find that library at run-time (rpath). I.e. for each `-L<dir>` option you need to have a corresponding `-Wl,-rpath,<dir>` option. `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'` is a bit magic because it looks for the shared libraries in the same directory where the executable is, so that you can move the directory with your application and the shared libraries anywhere you please without having to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

When linking specifying the full path to the shared library, like in the first command, it sets both paths.

Answer (score 1):

Linker gets the library name from the -l option using the rules described here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Every shared library has a special name called the 'soname'. The 'soname' format is this:

lib-< library_name >.so.< version_number >

Then you need to use -l which will skip the first "lib" and the extension of the library.

You can also use LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to specify the lib's directory as you have already done with passing it through the -L option.

Comment: I would suggest using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` only as the last resort. Link your applications correctly using `-Wl,-rpath` option.